# link problem with <div> encapsulated inside tag <a> with 2 columns

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, sass, flexbox

When I wrote this code with a global tag `<a>`, no problem the link id defined and appears at bottom everywhere my mouse is.

```
        <a class="link" href="opencl/toto.htm">
          <div class="enve d-flex">
            <div class="picture">
              <figure class="figure" style="background-image: url('images/desert.jpg');">
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
              <span class="keywords">keyword1 - keyword2</span>
              <h6 class="title">
                ************************** Title 1
              </h6>
              <div class="stats">
                <span>
                  <span class="pstat">
                    <svg class="stats-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path
                        d="M17 4h3v16h-3zM5 14h3v6H5zm6-5h3v11h-3z"
                      ></path>
                      <title>Difficulté</title>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="stat-text">
                      <span>Facile</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <span class="pstat">
                    <svg class="stats-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path
                        d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zM12 20c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"
                      ></path>
                      <path
                        d="M12.5 7H11v6l5.25 3.15.75-1.23-4.5-2.67z"
                      ></path>
                      <title>Durée</title>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="stat-text">
                      <span>20 heures</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </span>                  
              </div>
              <div class="explication">
                Explanation about that
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
```

result ok:

[image]

but now, I would want to have a link for the picture which covers all the div picture, and another link which covers the second column (description), but it seems there is a problem with container (flexbox, bootstrap) and I don't have solution to resolve this problem (and the both links have to appear at the bottom of the page when the mouse is hover the picture or the second column (like href does)).. Is it possible to do that?

the code not ok with the result:

```
          <div class="enve d-flex">
            <a class="link" href="opencl/toto.htm">
            <div class="picture">
              <figure class="figure" style="background-image: url('images/desert.jpg');">
              </figure>
            </div>
            </a>
            <a class="link" href="opencl/titi.htm">
            <div class="description">
              <span class="keywords">keyword1 - keyword2</span>
              <h6 class="title">
                ************************** Title 1
              </h6>
              <div class="stats">
                <span>
                  <span class="pstat">
                    <svg class="stats-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path
                        d="M17 4h3v16h-3zM5 14h3v6H5zm6-5h3v11h-3z"
                      ></path>
                      <title>Difficulté</title>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="stat-text">
                      <span>Facile</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <span class="pstat">
                    <svg class="stats-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path
                        d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zM12 20c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"
                      ></path>
                      <path
                        d="M12.5 7H11v6l5.25 3.15.75-1.23-4.5-2.67z"
                      ></path>
                      <title>Durée</title>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="stat-text">
                      <span>20 heures</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </span>                  
              </div>
              <div class="explication">
                Explanation about that
              </div>
            </div>
           </a>
          </div>
```

and the result not ok with the two links:

[image]

the CSS code (scss in fact)

```
.picture{
  background-color: rgb(0, 131, 143);
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 270px;
  .figure{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    background-size: cover;
    //background-color: #e0e0e0;
    background-position: center;
  }
}
.enve{
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.enve:hover{
  transition: box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
}

.description{
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.625rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 16px;
  width: 100%;
  .title{
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.625rem;
  }
 
}
.link{
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  &:hover{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.stats{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.625rem;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  .pstat{
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 24px;
    .stats-icon{
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
      margin-right: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  }
}
```

when I clear the class `d-flex` the result is ok but of course the columns have to be replaced by row.. and I want column...

[image]

Comment: Please add your corresponing css as well. Seems like a styling issue.

Comment: @MincedMeatMole i have added the css code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

What was happening is the following: display flex tries to distribute space in a div as needed when you dont define a min-width for an element. As a-tags are inline blocks they automatically collapse to a width of 0; As a background-image also doesn't add to the width your image on the left side collapsed.

Adding a min-width to the .picture class fixes this for example (the percentage-width also does nothing here).

For showing the items in a row instead of a column I just added flex-direction: row to the .enve container (also display-flex as the d-flex class didn't do that for me).

Hope this helps ^^

For a more in-depth look at flexbox I would recommend reading this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.picture{
  background-color: rgb(0, 131, 143);
  //flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 270px;
  min-width: 270px;
  }
  .picture .figure{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    background-size: cover;
    //background-color: #e0e0e0;
    background-position: center;
  }
.enve{
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.enve:hover{
  transition: box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
}

.description{
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.625rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
.description .title{
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.625rem;
  }
.link{
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  &:hover{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.stats{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.625rem;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.stats .pstat{
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
  .stats .pstat .stats-icon{
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
      margin-right: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="enve">
            <a class="link" href="opencl/toto.htm">
            <div class="picture">
              <figure class="figure" style="background-image: url('images/desert.jpg');">
              </figure>
            </div>
            </a>
            <a class="link" href="opencl/titi.htm">
            <div class="description">
              <span class="keywords">keyword1 - keyword2</span>
              <h6 class="title">
                ************************** Title 1
              </h6>
              <div class="stats">
                <span>
                  <span class="pstat">
                    <svg class="stats-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path
                        d="M17 4h3v16h-3zM5 14h3v6H5zm6-5h3v11h-3z"
                      ></path>
                      <title>Difficulté</title>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="stat-text">
                      <span>Facile</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <span class="pstat">
                    <svg class="stats-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path
                        d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zM12 20c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"
                      ></path>
                      <path
                        d="M12.5 7H11v6l5.25 3.15.75-1.23-4.5-2.67z"
                      ></path>
                      <title>Durée</title>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="stat-text">
                      <span>20 heures</span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </span>                  
              </div>
              <div class="explication">
                Explanation about that
              </div>
            </div>
           </a>
          </div>
```

Comment: yes the min-width for the picture does the job....thank you very much for your help...!!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a CSS problem, are you sure that your first link has a size of 50% ?

```
<a class="link" href="opencl/toto.htm">  <!-- This a should have a 50% width and display block -->
    <div class="picture"> <!-- This div should have a 100% width -->
        <figure class="figure" style="background-image: url('images/desert.jpg');">  <!-- This figure should have a 100% width -->
        </figure>
    </div>
</a>
```

Also, if this doesnt solve your problem, keep in mind that you can use

```
onclick="window.location.href='myLink'"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,   i have added the css code..i dont see errors.. maybe i have forgotten something... for the jqyuery, yes i know, but i need to have the link displayed and i think window.location doesnt display it

Comment: Your tag <a class"link"></a> doesnt have a 40% width so by default it is 0. Just add a class to this tag and the width and it should be ok :)

Comment: no its not good, i dont see change... but i have completed my question..when i clear the class flexbox `d-flex` i have the both links but with 2 rows and not column (normal when d-flex is cleared)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with the [onclick()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event

```
<div onclick="window.location.href='https://google.com'">somediv</div>
```

unfortunately the links doesnt appear at the bottom of the page. I think thats only possible with an href.

Comment: thanks for your respons, yes i know this trick, but i need to have the link displayed..